Getting npm ERR! code ENOMEM when trying to install npm in a remix project
When I run npm install in my Remix js project, I get the following errors:
npm ERR! code ENOMEM
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! errno -12
npm ERR! spawn ENOMEM

I've already tried the following commands but still getting the above errors:
export NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=4096
sudo /bin/dd if=/dev/zero of=/var/swap.1 bs=1M count=1024
sudo /sbin/mkswap /var/swap.1
sudo /sbin/swapon /var/swap.1 

Then I tried installing with htop on to see the live preview of Mem and Cpu usage and here's the result:

It uses up all of the Cpu, Mem and Swp Mem of the server. So, what can I do to resolve this error?
Thanks!

I solved this by increasing the swap memory.
So I basically did the following:
Creating the swap memory called swap.1 of 4gb:
sudo /bin/dd if=/dev/zero of=/var/swap.1 bs=4M count=1024

Initializing the swap file for swapping usage:
sudo /sbin/mkswap /var/swap.1

Activating the swap space:
sudo /sbin/swapon /var/swap.1 

